# XMLWriter and select to MS SQL database

Tags: c#, xml

I have an sql query, selects some data from a 2 table.I get these datas from the table. I want create a xml file from the data. My program code:

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sConnectionString;
    sConnectionString = "Data Source=SERWER;Initial Catalog=baza;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user; Password=pass;";
    SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
    objConn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter faktura = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  [t0].[Faktura] as 'InvoiceNumber', [t0].[FATrN_Data2] as 'Date', [t0].[FATrN_Data3] as 'InvoiceIssueDate',  DATEADD(DD, 90, [t0].[FATrN_Data3]) as 'InvoiceDueDate', '90' as 'PaymentTerms', 'I' as 'PaymentTermsReferenceDate' FROM [CDN].[INEcodFANaglo] AS [t0] WHERE ([t0].[TrN_GIDNumer] = '1015871') AND ([t0].[TrN_GIDTyp] = '2033')", objConn);

    SqlDataAdapter paymentmethod1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT  'P' as 'CODE', 'Przelew' as 'Description' FROM [CDN].[INEcodFANaglo] AS [t0] WHERE ([t0].[TrN_GIDNumer] = '1015871') AND ([t0].[TrN_GIDTyp] = '2033')", objConn);

    DataSet ds = new DataSet("Invoice");
    faktura.Fill(ds, "InvoiceHeader");

    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
    ds.WriteXml(@"c:\test1.xml");
    stream.Position = 0;

    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"c:\test1.xml");
    XElement invoice = doc.Element("Invoice");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable("PaymentMethod");
    paymentmethod1.Fill(dt);

    stream = new MemoryStream();
    dt.WriteXml(@"c:\test1.xml");
    stream.Position = 0;
    XElement paymentMethod = XElement.Load(@"c:\test1.xml");

    invoice.Add(paymentMethod);
}
}
}
```

the problem is that the program saves only    invoice.Add(paymentMethod); on XML file test1.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <PaymentMethod>
    <CODE>P</CODE>
    <Description>Przelew</Description>
  </PaymentMethod>
</DocumentElement>
```

Why not save `faktura.Fill(ds, "InvoiceHeader");`?

Comment: Are you sure that this is C?

Comment: ACK @ Yunnosch. This does look a lot like C#.

Comment: You're not doing anything with your stream objects. Is that intentional? I suspect that you intended to do something like the example shown in the [MSDN docs for DataSet.WriteXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa57x5f2(v=vs.110).aspx)